# Force layout to occur to guarantee the width won't change after layout finishes

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension, ios8-today-widget

I am programmatically creating a `UICollectionView` in `viewDidLoad` and then setting auto layout constraints on it. I need to know exactly what the collection view's width will be after it is displayed to the user, but I need that information in `viewDidLoad` (cannot use `willLayoutSubviews` etc).

How do you force layout to occur so I can guarantee the width will update to be the real width in `viewDidLoad`?

```
//viewDidLoad:
let collectionView = //...
self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
//add constraints here
let wid = collectionView.frame.size.width //0

//viewDidAppear:
let wid = collectionView.frame.size.width //603
```

I have tried calling `self.view.layoutSubviews()` but this didn't resolve the issue entirely. It changed `wid` to 720 instead of 0, but that's not correct.

I am attempting this in a Today extension, which may differ from a traditional view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use `viewWillAppear:`. The view will have loaded with the correct frame and you can then create the collection view before the view actually displays.

Comment: I cannot use `willWillAppear` because this affects the behavior of my extension undesirably. What I'm changing based on the width must be set before `viewWillAppear` and only set once.

Comment: Are you setting the width to a certain value? Or are you setting the autolayout constraints based on it's surrounding views?

Comment: I'm changing an auto layout constraint constant after performing a calculation using the collection view width. The undesirable behavior of doing that in `viewWillAppear` is the extension grows in height while it's loading then once it's done loading it shrinks. I need to set it earlier so it's always the same height.

Comment: The width of the collection view is dynamic - whatever the width of the Today view is for the device it's running on (it has leading and trailing to the superview.

Comment: Also on the iPad, the width reported in `viewWillAppear` isn't the width reported in `viewDidAppear` - it's off by quite a bit.